# Spring + TestNG Autowiring failure - NOT due to "new"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, testng

Having an issue with Spring Autowiring.  I have an Integration Test class declared as follows:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public abstract class BaseIntegrationTest
        extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
    @Autowired
    protected TestProperties properties;
//... more stuff here
}
```

The Context configuration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.ourcompany.myapp.it"},
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(value = com.inin.wfm.it.config.ConfigPackageExcludeFilter.class, type = FilterType.CUSTOM))
public class TestConfig {
    private TestProperties testProperties;
    private PropertyService propertyService;

    //This both creates and registers the bean with Spring
    @Bean
    public TestProperties getTestProperties() throws IOException {

        if (testProperties == null) {
            testProperties = new TestProperties(propertyService());
        }
        return testProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public PropertyService propertyService() throws IOException {
        if (propertyService == null) {

            AppAdminConfig config = new AppAdminConfig.Builder(PropertyService.getEnvironment(), TestConfigKey.ApplicationId)
                .checkPropertyHasValue(GlobalConfigKey.KafkaBrokerList.key())
                .checkPropertyHasValue(GlobalConfigKey.ZookeeperList.key())
                .build();

            propertyService = new PropertyService(config.getPropertiesConfig());
            propertyService.initialize();
        }

        return propertyService;
    }
}
```

And this is the bean I'm having trouble with:

```
@Configurable
public class TestProperties {
    private PropertyService propertyService;

    public TestProperties(PropertyService propertyService) {
        this.propertyService = propertyService;
    }
    public String getCacheUri(){
        return propertyService.getPropertyRegistry().getString(TestConfigKey.CacheUri.key(), Default.CACHE_URI);
    }
}
```

I have multiple Test implementation classes that extend BaseIntegrationTest.  All of them but one have valid references to their TestProperties field, but exactly one of the test implementation classes is getting a Null Pointer and throwing an NPE when an attempt is made to reference this.

So the question is, why is Spring `@Autowire` working fine for 3 different classes that extend the same base class, but wiring up `null` for the fourth?  There is no additional configuration logic in any of the implementations.

For MCVE completeness, here's the bare bones of my impl class

```
public class CacheIT
        extends BaseIntegrationTest {
    @Test
public void testUserCache() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        String uri = properties.getCacheUri() //TODO - NPE here
    }
}
```

I know there's not much to go on... I've been working with Spring for a long time and haven't seen it do this kind of thing before.  According to everything I can see it should be working.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for - the only configuration in any of the impls is `extends BaseIntegrationTest`

Comment: Please provide an MCVE and a stack trace of the error. It's not obvious from what you've shown.

Comment: It's not obvious with all the code, either... The stack trace is literally one line, Null Pointer Exception where the `properties` object is referenced

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.inin.wfm.it.test.CacheIT.testUserCache(CacheIT.java:81)`

Comment: CacheFactory factory = new MemcachedCacheFactory(properties.getCacheUri()); //TODO

Comment: Not much to go on, so a wild stab in the dark: try `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)`. That will force CGLIB (class-based) proxies, rather than JDK-dynamic (interface-based) proxies.  From what I've seen in the past, Spring is more comfortable auto-wiring class-based proxies.

Comment: @MrSpoon I agree there's not much to go on... not much more to go on sitting here in front of the code.  I was really hoping to be able to say you should investigate blindfolded fencing as a career option, but alas your suggestion didn't change anything.  I also tried removing that annotation entirely and it appeared to have no effect on my test runs at all

Comment: Added, it's another bean declared in the same class

Comment: Any example I try works. Please produce something minimal that we can plug and play and see the behavior you are describing.

Comment: Perhaps another test class? This is one of four test classes

Comment: Makes no difference, with those I tried.